# Stretch image of button image from code

Tags: android

I'm programatically adding imagebuttons to my layout, but the problem is that I can't control the size of the images retrieved from the database so it results in some of them being too small. I'd like to know if there's any way to define to the image button to stretch the displayed image.

```
        for(DataModel m : list){
            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
            byte[] Convert = Base64.decode(m.GetImage(), Base64.DEFAULT );
            btn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Convert, 0, Convert.length));

            btn.setId(Integer.parseInt(m.GetFoodId()));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // To do later                      
                }
            });
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,200));
            ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(btn);
        }
```

Comment: try btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); i think thats how you do that

Comment: @JRowan: Thanks, solved my problem, if you post it as answer, I'll accept it

Comment: no problem, glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setScaleType method of imageview

```
btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Answer (score 0):

hey if you do scale type fitxy then your image show Stretch, but if you do  scale type  center inside then it work proper, plase check out